# Where do we get the framework's name for Carthage dependency management?

Tags: frameworks, dependencies, cocoapods, carthage

My question is, it seems like difficult to get the framework cartfile name in Carthage whereas in CocoaPods it is too easy by using this like `https://cocoapods.org/` we just copy and paste it.

Is there any websites or place to get all the frameworks cartfile name for Carthage dependency tool?

Answer (score 1):

CocoaPods is a centralized dependency manager, which is why you have cocoa pods site listing out all of the available pods ready to be integrated into your awesome project.

[Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#differences-between-carthage-and-cocoapods) is exactly opposite of that,

> By contrast, Carthage has been created as a decentralized dependency
>   manager. There is no central list of projects, which reduces
>   maintenance work and avoids any central point of failure. However,
>   project discovery is more difficult—users must resort to GitHub’s
>   Trending pages or similar.

Comment: Thanks @GoodSp. Basically Which one is the best tool to integrate a third party frameworks?. I have researched some where in net that saying, for Objective C projects they preferred for CocoaPods for Swift projects preferred Carthage. Is it right approach?